# is it possible to update SQL file's rows using dropbox api?

Tags: python, sql, dropbox

There are people saying no it doesn't and something saying probably so I am confused can I update a SQL file's rows and their values and the sql file is in the dropbox storage. I am using sqlite3 for this purpose and If its not possible to update in dropbox can I use any other cloud storage api for this like google drive or mega?
Thank you
Language- Python

Comment: Can you update other file types?

Comment: no idea about others as well

Answer (score 0):

[The Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) offers the ability to upload and download files of any file type, including database files.

It doesn't offer special support for connecting to and querying database files directly on the Dropbox servers, but I'll pass this along as a feature request. I can't promise if or when that might be implemented though.

That being the case, you'd have to download the entire database file and then use it locally (and re-upload the new version if there are any changes).